# android studio AsyncTask not intenting and context.finish crashes

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i am new to android,and trying to use `AsyncTask` to get a connection to mysql from the server

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


    if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
    {

         Intent intent = new Intent(context,profile.class);
        //not usefull
        //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        ((Activity)context).finish();
        Toast.makeText(context, "done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }else //..... the rest of the code .....//
}
```

everything works fine but when the result is true it doesn't intent to the new activity
and by using `((Activity)context).finish();` it will crash
the app always toast done

`context` is defined `Context context` , i got its value from `MainActivity` by typing `this`

Comment: post the error log for crash with question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using `this` is reference to the activity, I think you should be referencing the `application context` to start an activity.**

```
if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
{


Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),profile.class);

context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);

((YourActivityName)context).finish();

Toast.makeText(context, "done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



}else //..... the rest of the code .....//
```